# Visual Studio, Asp.net connection string

Tags: asp.net

In the Visual Studio, it will generate datasource like this :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorksConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT top 10 * FROM [Address]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

when run it, it will say 'invalid object'. then I found it out, it should be

```
[AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
```

The connection string is

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AdventureWorksConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Then how to config in VS to use this format ?

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Maybe apart from what Oded already pointed out, the `Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks` is missing and your query is directed against the *master* database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default schema for the logged in database user is probably `[dbo]`, not `[Person]`. You need to qualify the schema name in such a case.

Your select command should be:

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM [Person].[Address]
```

Comment: @user595234 - Apologies, you are correct. You need to qualify the schema if the user is not setup to use that one by default.